# Getting different results while using different(but correct) algorithms to find LU Decomposition in Python. Both Algorithms are working fine in Java

Tags: java, python-3.x, algorithm, graph-algorithm

```
Matrix:
2  -1  -1
-1   3  -1
-1  -1  3
```

I know there are in-built modules to find the LU decomposition, but this is an algorithms assignment so I'm refraining to use them.

I'm using two algorithms:

1. [Doolittle's Algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwje7_yapcrrAhUIIbcAHSC9DZ8QFjAQegQICxAR&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fdoolittle-algorithm-lu-decomposition%2F&usg=AOvVaw0ZMMF4KplsAnqDR7oHI0t2) (This one is giving the correct answer)
2. [Algorithm provided in "Introduction to Algorithms book"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jongsun_Park2/publication/220624910/figure/fig4/AS:668837582213157@1536474714757/a-LU-decomposition-pseudocode-b-Example-on-LU-decomposition.png) (This one is not. But working fine in Java).

Doolittle's Algorithm Implementation

```
def luDecomposition(mat, n):
    lower = [[0.0 for _ in range(n)]
             for _ in range(n)]
    upper = [[0.0 for _ in range(n)]
             for _ in range(n)]

    # Decomposing matrix into Upper
    # and Lower triangular matrix
    for i in range(n):

        # Upper Triangular
        for k in range(i, n):

            # Summation of L(i, j) * U(j, k)
            total = 0.0
            for j in range(i):
                total += (lower[i][j] * upper[j][k])

                # Evaluating U(i, k)
            upper[i][k] = mat[i][k] - total

            # Lower Triangular
        for k in range(i, n):
            if i == k:
                lower[i][i] = 1.0  # Diagonal as 1
            else:

                # Summation of L(k, j) * U(j, i)
                total = 0.0
                for j in range(i):
                    total += (lower[k][j] * upper[j][i])

                    # Evaluating L(k, i)
                lower[k][i] = (mat[k][i] - total) / upper[i][i]

    return lower, upper
```

Output:

```
Lower Triangular Matrix:      Upper Triangular Matrix:
[[ 1.   0.   0. ]                [[ 2.  -1.  -1. ]
 [-0.5  1.   0. ]                 [ 0.   2.5 -1.5]
 [-0.5 -0.6  1. ]]                [ 0.   0.   1.6]]
```

2. Implementation according to the book.

   ```
   def luDecomposition(mat, n):

       # Initializing the matrices
       lower = np.array([[0.0]*n for _ in range(n)])
       for i in range(n):
           lower[i][i] = 1.0

       upper = np.array([[0.0]*n for _ in range(n)])

       # Decomposing matrix into Upper
       # and Lower triangular matrix
       for k in range(n):
           upper[k][k] = mat[k][k]

           for a in range(k + 1, n):
               lower[a][k] = mat[a][k] / upper[k][k]
               upper[k][a] = mat[k][a]

           for x in range(k + 1, n):
               for y in range(k + 1, n):
                   mat[x][y] -= lower[x][k] * upper[k][y]

       return lower, upper
   ```

Output:

```
Lower Triangular Matrix:       Upper Triangular Matrix:
[[ 1.   0.   0. ]              [[ 2. -1. -1.]
 [-0.5  1.   0. ]               [ 0.  2. -1.]
 [-0.5 -0.5  1. ]]              [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

I've checked multiple times and the codes are implemented correctly.

****Only if you are interested:****
This is part of an assignment to find the number of spanning trees of a graph by using [Kirchoff's Theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwis3PWjqMrrAhUSg-YKHZHFD84QtwIwAHoECAEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Ftotal-number-spanning-trees-graph%2F&usg=AOvVaw3nLKEwivcClYcC0U-VV2pF). In step 4 of the theorem, the cofactor is calculated using LU decomposition to reduce calculations. The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/nakulp21/Advanced_Algorithms/blob/master/Assignment%201.py)

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq637041675459839) this. Are you sure you have taken into account that the array (that you pass as argument) is mutated, and so no longer the same *after* the call? Maybe you ran the two algorithms in sequence without re-initialising the original array?

Comment: @trincot No I made sure that the array was mutable. I've answered the question myself pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution from reddit. Original answer and follow-up questions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/il4div/trying_to_find_lu_decomposition_of_a_matrix/)

---

I was passing the matrix as a numpy array that is why I got the wrong result.

```
luDecomposition(np.array([[2,-1,-1],[-1,3,-1],[-1,-1,3]]), 3)
```

gives the wrong result but

```
luDecomposition([[2,-1,-1],[-1,3,-1],[-1,-1,3]], 3)
```

gives the correct one. This is because numpy takes np.array([[2,-1,-1],[-1,3,-1],[-1,-1,3]]) to be a matrix of integers and the -= operator will not change that datatype:

To deal with this, you could do

```
mat = np.asarray(mat, dtype=float)  # or complex or whatever
```

however altering a matrix that was passed as an argument like this is generally bad practice (unexpected side effects are bad, in general), so it's probably best to make a copy with something like:

```
mat = np.array(mat, dtype=float)
mat = np.asarray(mat, dtype=float).copy()
```

I'm not actually sure which is better, but I would hazard a guess that the second is faster if mat is already an array of an appropriate type (but it makes a copy twice otherwise).

---

The reason Doolittle's algorithm gave the correct answer because it wasn't altering the matrix and the other algorithm did.